# MSSQL data insertion with Python and pypyodbc - Params must be in a list, tuple

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pypyodbc

I'm attempting to write (I can read fine) values to a MSSQL instance. My code resembles:

```
import pypyodbc
lst = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
connection = pypyodbc.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO table (a, b, c)VALUES(?,?,?)", lst)
```

This returns: Params must be in a list, tuple. I've read similar posts which suggest trying lst = list(['val1, 'val2', val3'])
But this returns: list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
I've also tried variations of cursor.execute(), but same problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the difference between [`cursor.execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15):

> `.execute ( operation [, parameters ])`
>
> Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to variables in the operation.

and [`cursor.executemany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany):

> `.executemany ( operation , seq_of_parameters )`
>
> Prepare a database operation (query or command) and then **execute it against all parameter sequences or mappings found in the sequence** seq_of_parameters .

So, if you are executing your query for only **one** set of values, call it like this:

```
values = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (?,?,?)", [values])
```

Or, for multiple sets of values:

```
values1 = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
values2 = ['val3', 'val2', 'val1']
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (?,?,?)", [values1, values2])
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it now returns: ('HY000', 'The SQL contains 3 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied')

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same code you provided in your question? Because there are only 3 parameter placeholders.